# What Data is Taken Into Account when using VSBuild@1 in a Azure Devops build pipeline?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, yaml

I have a step in my build pipeline that looks like this:

```yaml
      - task: VSBuild@1
        inputs:
          solution: '$(solution)'
          msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
          platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
          configuration: '${{ parameters.configuration }}'
```

The artifacts end up being put into a .zip archive, and all is well, and I can extract that and copy it to the destination of my choice.  But I'm wondering what, if anything, is done with information in the .pubxml file, which looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Texas</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>\\subdomain.webserver.com\qa\WebServices\APILocation\Texas</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Later in my build pipeline, I'd like to copy the artifacts to the location specified in the publishUrl node of that .pubxml file. How can I access that information from within the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to copy the artifacts to the location specified in the publishUrl node of that .pubxml file. How can I access that information from within the pipeline?

You could deploy the pipeline with the .pubxml file:

```
  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:PublishProfile=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\xxx\Properties\PublishProfiles\YourProfile.pubxml'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '${{ parameters.configuration }}'
```

And if you have any other argument want to override the it in the build arguments，like:

```
/p:publishUrl=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but it turns out that to use it, I essentially need the information in the xxx part of the URL (in your example).  But if I know that, I also know the value I am trying to get (at least in the codebase I am working in).  So it doesn't really help. But it's a good answer for others with a similar problem.